# Python regex - split string at back to back line breaks with [possibly] spaces in between

Tags: python, regex, line-breaks

I want to do exactly what the title says. So I have the following string shown below and I want to be able to find all double line breaks (possibly with spaces in between like below, possibly not):

```
input = """4. A drawer locli:ing device for locl@.ing ,t  
     15 tier of draivers, one of which is lock controllecl, comprising

     twc, drawer retainina m--mbe , rs loica@ted at the front of th-. 
     drawer@' oiie acljacept each side of the tier of dra,-wers ar,d
      arranged to 
     overlap the front of the,"""

output = re.finditer('\n[\S+]\n', nameString)?????????????????????

output[0] = "4. A drawer locli:ing device for locl@.ing ,t  
     15 tier of draivers, one of which is lock controllecl, comprising"
output[1] = "twc, drawer retainina m--mbe , rs loica@ted at the front of th-. 
     drawer@' oiie acljacept each side of the tier of dra,-wers ar,d
      arranged to 
     overlap the front of the,"
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I have rarely seen such horrible spelling, grammar, etiquette, and question asking skills in one place.

Comment: Alright I will update my code. And btw the comment about "spelling" was uncalled for because I got the input string from an OCR process and pasted it verbatim.

Comment: I never said the spelling was from you, just that it was horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
>>> data = """4. A drawer locli:ing device for locl@.ing ,t  
         15 tier of draivers, one of which is lock controllecl, comprising

         twc, drawer retainina m--mbe , rs loica@ted at the front of th-. 
         drawer@' oiie acljacept each side of the tier of dra,-wers ar,d
          arranged to 
         overlap the front of the,"""
```

And now we import regex:

```
>>> import re
```

And then we split it:

```
>>> r = re.split(r'\n\s*\n', data) # for more than 2 newlines: r'\n[\s\n]*\n'
```

Now display the results:

```
>>> r[0]
'4. A drawer locli:ing device for locl@.ing ,t  \n         15 tier of draivers, one of which is lock controllecl, comprising'
>>> r[1]
"         twc, drawer retainina m--mbe , rs loica@ted at the front of th-. \n         drawer@' oiie acljacept each side of the tier of dra,-wers ar,d\n          arranged to \n         overlap the front of the,"
```